# Behaivor of instances new-ed from the same StatefulWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have troubled with the behaivor of instances from the same class.

I made two instances of StatefulWidget(BodyLayout) class.
and switch them by BottomNavigationBar

But only one of `initState()` of BodyLayout is called.

I am confused by this behavior , `State` is shared each instances???

I want to each `initState()` is called separately.

Please help some hint.

These are full source code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new MyHomePage(),
        "/browser": (_) => new Text("not use"),
      }
    );
  }
}
class Article{
  String title;
  String url;
  Article();
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title; 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _myLayouts = [];
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _myLayouts = [
      new BodyLayout("latest"),
      new BodyLayout("pop"),
    ];
  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    print("itemTapped :" +index.toString());
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index; 
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      //  title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _myLayouts[_currentIndex],

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          title: Text('latest'),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.business),
          title: Text('pop'),
        ),
      ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}


class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  final String mode;
  BodyLayout(this.mode);

  @override
  _BodyLayoutState createState() => _BodyLayoutState();
}
class _BodyLayoutState extends State<BodyLayout>{
  List<Article> articles = [];
  bool loading = true;
  int page = 1;
  @override 
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    print ("init:" + widget.mode);// this called only one time.....
    _callApi(); // this called only one time.....
  }

  void _callApi() {
    var a = Article();
    a.title = widget.mode;
    a.url = widget.mode;
    articles.add(a);
    setState((){
      loading = false;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(loading) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: articles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(articles[index].title),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused by this behavior , State is shared each instances???

Yes, it is. You need to provide unique keys to your widgets:

```dart
class BodyLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  BodyLayout(this.mode, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

...
    _myLayouts = [
      new BodyLayout("latest", key: Key('1')),
      new BodyLayout("pop", key: Key('2')),
    ];
```

and bam - it works:

```
I/flutter (12871): init:latest
I/flutter (12871): itemTapped :1
I/flutter (12871): init:pop
```

From the docs:

> A StatefulWidget keeps the same State object when moving from one location in the tree to another if its creator used a GlobalKey for its key.

So basically, if your widgets have the same key (or don't have one), they're interpreted as the same widget.

Comment: This idea really needs to be stated more clearly in the Flutter docs. It isn't quite clear out of the box that StatefulWidgets tend to share states when of the same type.